# Is the Weierstrass function given in Counterexamples in Analysis a typo?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $0 < a < 1$; let $b$ be an odd integer; let $ab > 1 + \frac{3\pi}{2}$; let 
$f: x \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 0}a^{n}\cos (b^{n}\pi x): \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. Then $f$ is everywhere continuous and nowhere differentiable.

On page 39 of [Counterexamples in Analysis](http://www.kryakin.org/am2/_Olmsted.pdf) (Dover edition), the authors write the Weierstrass function $f$ as $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0}b^{n}\cos (a^{n} \pi x)$; then I do not see how it can converge (of this "typo" series)...

If this is really an obvious typo, then there should already be someone that pointed it out; but so far I did not find any source doing this, so I ask here to clarify this point.

Comment: It's weird. In the index it's stated that there's an errata, but it's not included somehow.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you for feedback. Maybe I should contact the authors (if they are still alive. :))

Answer (score 1):

The typo is the constraints on $a$ and $b$. In the book it says that $b$ is an odd integer, it should actually be $a$. And $b$ should be $0<b<1$. That, or the $a$ and $b$ should be switched in the series.

To see this converges, just use the Weierstrass M-test. $|a^n\cos(b^n \pi x)|\leq a^n$ and $\sum a^n$ converges.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. The remedy I guess is like yours: $a$ should be put where $b$ is and $b$ should be put where $a$ is.

Comment: @GudsonChou If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#Construction you'll see they have the same definition with $a$ and $b$ switched.

Comment: Oh, right, thanks for that. Now I tend to maintain more that it is simply a typo.

Comment: @GudsonChou Actually the proof it converges is really straightforward. Just use Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Sorry? Yes, it is clear that it converges; but this is not my question :)

Comment: @GudsonChou Of course. I just said "tedious" and I was wrong. I was just correcting myself. I thought it would be more tedious than it actually is.

Comment: Uh..., let me clarify my question: Under the assumptions in my question, the series $x \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 0}a^{n}\cos (b^{n}\pi x)$ converges; but I do not see how $x \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 0}b^{n}\cos (a^{n}\pi x)$ can converge (so I suspect the latter admits some typo) :)

Comment: @GudsonChou You're correct that it's a typo. :)